# how can 2 objects get the lock at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

the following code uses Lock object in order to avoid deadlock situation.

1. in function impendingBow, how can 2 objects get at the same time the lock:
   the current object and the Friend bower ?

   ```
   myLock = lock.tryLock();
   yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
   ```
2. is it because it's 2 different objects? 
   if yes, does it mean that it's enough to use one lock for few objects?
3. can anyone explain how we avoid deadlock in this implementation ?

this is the full code:

```
  public class Safelock {
    static class Friend {
       private final String name;
       private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Friend(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public boolean impendingBow(Friend bower) {
        Boolean myLock = false;
        Boolean yourLock = false;
        try {
            myLock = lock.tryLock();
            yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
        } finally {
            if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
                if (myLock) {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                if (yourLock) {
                    bower.lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
        return myLock && yourLock;
    }

    public void bow(Friend bower) {
        if (impendingBow(bower)) {
            try {
                System.out.format("%s: %s has"
                    + " bowed to me!%n", 
                    this.name, bower.getName());
                bower.bowBack(this);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
                bower.lock.unlock();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.format("%s: %s started"
                + " to bow to me, but saw that"
                + " I was already bowing to"
                + " him.%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
        System.out.format("%s: %s has" +
            " bowed back to me!%n",
            this.name, bower.getName());
    }
}

static class BowLoop implements Runnable {
    private Friend bower;
    private Friend bowee;

    public BowLoop(Friend bower, Friend bowee) {
        this.bower = bower;
        this.bowee = bowee;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (;;) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            bowee.bow(bower);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my mistake, just noticed that each object has its own lock instance.

Comment: You are able to delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can 2 objects get at the same time the lock

Two objects means 2 independant locks. There is not what is sometime called a *giant* lock. There are many individual locks.

> is it because it's 2 different objects? if yes, does it mean that it's enough to use one lock for few objects

Yes, when you have a group of objects for which modifications need to be synchronized, you may use only one lock. In this case, you can choose any of your objects, or a new dedicated object, to use as a lock for the group.

> can anyone explain how we avoid deadlock in this implementation ?

To avoid deadlocks, you must lock objects always in the same order. This is what you do, so no deadlock in your program. More precisely, when you have two locks A and B, one of your threads can lock A then B, or B only (A may or may not already be locked by another thread), or A only (B may or may not already be locked by another thread). There will never be a deadlock in those situations. If one of your threads could lock B then A, there would be a deadlock. This is not the case.

**A good way to avoid dead locks is to write a dependency graph on your locks. Each lock is an object in this graph and dependencies are locks that *may* be acquired in a specific order by threads. Then, to get a dead-lock, there must be a [wait-for graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph) that has a loop. But since a wait-for graph is a subgraph of your dependency graph, and since your dependency graph has no loop, then no dead-lock is possible.**

Answer (score 0):

There are two different lock instances here, so taking one will not interfere with the other.

A deadlock occurs when one thread takes a lock X and a another thread takes lock Y. The first thread then attempts to take lock Y, and waits for it to be released. In the meanwhile, the second thread attempts to take lock X, and waits for it to be released. Since both threads are waiting for each other, the operation can never be completed, and the threads are deadlocked.

Here, the code used [`tryLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock--), which does not wait if it cannot acquire the lock. Instead, it immediately returns `false`. Since the threads don't block until the locks are acquired, this snippet can never result in a deadlock.